# In Deut 32:27 how would the adversaries misjudge?

Tags: deuteronomy, moses

> Deuteronomy 32:25-27
>   25‘Outside the sword will bereave, And inside
>   terror— Both young man and virgin, The nursling with the man of gray
>   hair. 26  ‘I would have said, “I will cut them to pieces, I will
>   remove the memory of them from men,” **27  Had I not feared the
>   provocation by the enemy, That their adversaries would misjudge, That
>   they would say, “Our hand is [h]triumphant, And the Lord has not done
>   all this.”’**

In Deuteronomy 32:25-27, could someone please explain the meaning of the following?

> Deuteronomy 32:27
>   27 Had I not feared the provocation by the enemy, That
>   their adversaries would misjudge, That they would say, “Our hand is
>   [h]triumphant, And the Lord has not done all this.”’

I do Not understand who and/or what instigated the fear of the provocation by the enemy, and why, what or how adversaries would misjudge? (LOL, I'm just totally lost when it comes to understanding the meaning of Deuteronomy 32:27)
Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: To understand any verse we need to understand the context and for that i would recommend commentaries which help to comprehend the 'why', 'who' said 'what' to 'whom'. You can try the following link, Hope it will help you to get the answer,  [bible Hub](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/mhcw/deuteronomy/32.htm) .

Answer (score 3):

It means that God would have wiped out the sinful and unfaithful nation of Israel and punished them by the hands of their enemies. The only reason God refrains from doing so is because the nations would have thought that they are stronger than Yahweh the God of Israel, and that Yahweh is helpless against their mighty gods. This would have brought a huge desecration to God's name so he refrains from letting the enemy destroy Israel; if not for that, the Israelites would have deserved this punishment for being so unfaithful to God.

Compare this argument to the argument by Moses in Numbers 14:15-16

> If you put all these people to death, leaving none alive, the nations
>   who have heard this report about you will say, 16 ‘The Lord was not
>   able to bring these people into the land he promised them on oath, so
>   he slaughtered them in the wilderness.’

Indeed God listens to Moses' argument and refrains from wiping out the nation of Israel. The same argument is used here in Deut. 32:27.

Hope this helps.